# Getting length of each line inside polygon based on symbology breakdown of line file using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I'm working in ArcGIS Pro 2.7.2 on trying to get the length of lines inside a polygon based on the groups classified for symbolizing the lines (in this case the lines represent pipe and are classified into 10 different groups). It is one polyline geodatabase file of pipe that I have queried for what I need and symbolized based on two attributes, operating pressure and diameter. I have a polygon file of rectangles areas and I want to find out the length of each classified main, in each rectangle, in a new attribute field that corresponds to the classified group (i.e. there would be 10 new attribute fields to match with each classified group). Each polygon would show a length if a particular group or groups are within the polygon and  for the groups that are not within the polygon.

Is there a geoprocessing tool (or tools) that could help with this?

This is a project that will be going on for a few years so I'm trying to avoid selecting and exporting each classified group and calculating the fields in the polygon file. The polyline geodatabase it will be an relatively constant updated data set based on retirements and new installs.

Below is an image of how the lines are classified

[image: Classified groups by symbol]

Comment: Intersect and use pivot table in Excel.

Comment: Your title doesn't describe the way GIS operations generally function. Symbology is the result of processing to distinguish the areas intersected by the line geometry.  Length is one of the many properties available after splitting the features.